# Making publication quality tables in R from excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, excel, data-manipulation

[image]

I am looking to make quality tables in R directly from an excel spreadsheet. Is there any package that can easily accomplish this? For example, the picture above is a table that I want to recreate in R. I read the table in as a csv but kable will not output an image.

```
install.packages("magick")
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
library(kableExtra)
    kable(rawCSV, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
      kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>%
      row_spec(1, color = "red") %>%
      as_image()
    save_kable(a,"outtable1.png")
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you know RMarkdown? If yes then read: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html

Comment: Also without a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example we cannot know what you want

Comment: you could have a look at [tables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) package

Comment: When you import tables from Excel into R, you lose Excel's formatting. There's no way to get around this (as far as I know). Maybe you could export from Excel to html, and then from html to RMarkdown (mentioned above).

Comment: I updated the question a bit. Not sure if its much easier to help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it! I read the document in as a csv and then used the kable code below to save it to a document. Quite effective. Thank you all for your help.

```
# save table ---------
rawCSV <- read.csv("/Users/admin/Desktop/table2.csv")

kable(rawCSV, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("solid", "scale_down")) %>%
  #as_image()
  save_kable("/Users/admin/out1.png")
```